# Dictionary (key and arrays as value) to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert this dictionary with keys as data and values as list of arrays(length of list varry for each key):

```
d = {'2015-01-01': array([2.14326087, 3.57877791, 1.        , 3.37848844, 3.75323736,
        2.5       , 4.54818705]),
 '2015-01-02': array([5.01332283, 2.96643532, 7.30596244, 3.94960483, 2.58503318,
        4.7696893 , 7.46607457, 3.64545497, 3.98931486]),
 '2015-01-03': array([4.78131874, 2.54271806, 4.95111647, 2.27579913, 4.94445053])}
```

to pandas dataframe:

```
2015-01-01 | 4.78131874
2015-01-01 | 2.54271806
2015-01-01 | 4.95111647
2015-01-01 | 2.27579913
2015-01-01 | 4.94445053
.
.
.
2015-01-03 | 4.78131874
2015-01-03 | 3.57877791
2015-01-03 | 1
2015-01-03 | 3.37848844
2015-01-03 | 3.75323736
```

Comment: You mean you want keys to be columns? `2015-01-01`, `2015-01-02`, 2015-01-03` ? and the values of these keys to be rows for each of these columns? Or are you referring to the `to pandas dataframe` section in your question as the desired output?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far to get this into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: The solution shared by @BENY, is working and it is perfect. By using the `pd.Series(d).explode() ` , I am getting desired output. Thanks. I was trying to create a pandas dataframe, the above solutions give key as index, It can then be used to create a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `explode`

```
out = pd.Series(d).explode()
```